# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1' has no attribute 'pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

After trying to run `tensorboard --logdir dump_dir` I get `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1' has no attribute 'pywrap_tensorflow'`

Tensorboard version:

```
TensorBoard 1.13.1

python -c "from tensorboard import version; print(version.VERSION)"
1.13.1
```

Tensorflow version:

```
python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"
1.14.0-rc1
```

I have builded tensorflow from source, is it version mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `pip3 install --upgrade tensorboard` helped.

Comment: How so? In what way?

Comment: Seems the problem was that tensorboard version was incompatible with tensorflow version builded from source.

Comment: More specifically, I think `Tensorboard==1.13.1` requires `tensorflow==1.13.0rc2`. I tried it with `tensorflow==1.15.0` and it worked as well.